# How to count the string quantity between semicolon in a cell with script google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a Google Sheet, I have cells with multiple info in one cell (for example: "abc; def; 4f5").

I would like to make a SCRIPT (no formula) that allows me to know how many words in the cell separated by semicolons.

Example:

```
"abc; def; 4f5" ==> 3

"abc; def" ==> 2

"ABC;" ==> 1

"abc" ==> 1

"abc;def;;" ==> 2
```

It's been 2 days that I'm on it and I can not find any code that can do it.

Someone would have an idea of how to do it please.

Thank you.

Comment: You're expected to write the code, not just search for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or as a custom function.  Let say in cell A1 you have the first case "abc; def; 4f5", then in cell B1 place the formula =splitString(A1).  The value will be 3.  However if there are blanks between words it will be counted.

```
function splitString(string) {
  var array = string.split(";");
  if( array.length > 0 ) {
    while( array[array.length-1].trim() === "" ) {
      array = array.slice(0,array.length-1);
      if( array.length === 0 ) break;
    }
  }
  return array.length;
}
```

Comment: OP stated no formula. If you're going to use a formula, why not use inbuilt ones? `=COUNTIF(SPLIT(A1,";"),"<>")`

Comment: COUNTIF does not handle case 3 if trailing spaces.  And OP asked for a script.  This can be used either as custom functon or other ways.

Comment: TY but I had already try 'split' bit I have an error message :
ReferenceError: L'élément "split" n'est pas défini

Comment: Oki, the message is because, I had no ";" in my cell ^^

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what aspect of this you having an issue with, but the following might help.

```
function counter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];         // Get the first worksheet.
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:A1');   // Get the content of the first cell "abc; def; 4f5"
  range.activate();
  var content = range.getValue();
  content = content.replace(/;+/g, ';'); // strip double ;;
  var count = content.split(';').length;
  Logger.log("The content %s has %s words seperated by semicolons.", content, count);
}
```

Comment: TY but I had already try 'split' but I have an error message :
ReferenceError: L'élément "replace" n'est pas défini

Comment: Good. But,  I think `abc;def;;` will show 3 instead of 2, because of the trailing `;`.

Comment: Oki, the message is because, I had no ";" in my cell ^^